# Which versions of nvd3 and d3 are compatible in order to get rid of version issues

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a angular-nvd3 line chart.I'm facing some version issues.I'm facing this error:

```
Error: d.values is undefined
chart/</<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js:6220:69
```

I did a lot of browsing but unable to fix this error.I've followed this [url](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart) for installing required modules.But unable to fix this issue.Tried to downgrade d3.js but of no use.

Can u please specify which version of angular-nvd3,nvd3 and d3 are compatible to get rid of this error.

Comment: What version of AngularJS, D3 and NVD3 are you using? Can you set up a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) to reproduce your error?

Comment: please refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307562/facing-error-d-values-is-undefined-in-nvd3-line-chart# for error details

Comment: I don't know how to put the code in plunker

Comment: read this https://github.com/novus/nvd3#dependencies

Comment: My angular version -->  "1.4.9" ,d3 version -->3.3.6, nvd3 version -->1.8.2, angular-nvd3 version -->1.0.5

Comment: well your error does not speak anything about the version in all probables its the data issue.

Comment: I had referred this url http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/novus/nvd3/q/stackoverflow/17624111/nvd3-line-chart-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-39x39-of-undefined

Comment: It says that this type of issues occurs due to d3 and nvd3 version compatibilities

Comment: can anyone please help me out.Really stuck with this version compatibility issues

Comment: @dev777 were you able to fix that? I'm facing the same issue :(